# DataBind KnockoutJs with Devexpress Controls

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, knockout.js

I'm developing a website for a client using knockoutJs. However they want to use the DevExpress controls for DateEdit, Text fields with autocomplete and FileUpload. Its currnetly a traditional ASP.NET Webforms application but I would personally prefer to migrate them to MVC4.

Is it possible with either of the DevExpress ASP.NET or MVC controls to be able to bind with knockoutjs or is it a choice of DevExpress or knockoutjs?

Comment: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q471338 Quick Google search returns that as first result